# custom delete procedure devexpress schedule

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete appointment from list but I don't wont deteled that from my database. I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub schedulerControl_DeleteAppointmentFormShowing(sender As Object, e As AppointmentFormEventArgs) Handles schedulerControl.DeleteRecurrentAppointmentFormShowing
    Dim scheduler As DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl = CType(sender, DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl)
    Try
        If koneksiDB.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'proses simpan DB
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update Appointments set isdeleted = 1 where UniqueID = @Kode", koneksiDB)
            Dim apt As Appointment = schedulerControl.SelectedAppointments(0)
            Dim dr As DataRowView = CType(apt.GetSourceObject(schedulerStorage), DataRowView)
            Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt64(dr("UniqueID"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("kode", id)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            RefreshDB()
        Else
            MsgBox("Maaf koneksi dengan database terputus. harap memperbaiki koneksi terlebih dahulu.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Maaf, terjadi permasalahan teknis :" & Chr(13) & ex.Message & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Silakan catat dan hubungi pihak teknisi bila diperlukan.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and take the 30secs required to format your code as code

Answer (score 0):

The line where you add the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("kode", id)
```

you should add the `@` character and a capital K letter :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kode", id)
```

The `@` character is not necessary but considered best practices. However I think it is case sensitive, so don't forget the capital K.

[See this question for more details (Is it necessary to add a @ in front of an SqlParameter name?).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245510/is-it-necessary-to-add-a-in-front-of-an-sqlparameter-name)